# I am creating my own class. There's a type error that _Screen.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, typeerror

```
# Set up the screen
import turtle

class Screen(turtle.Screen()):
# Create and define an object
    def __init__(self, title, bgcolor, height, width, tracer = 0):
        turtle.Screen().__init__(self)
        # Assign attribute to our instance
        self.title = title
        self.bgcolor = bgcolor
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.tracer = tracer
```

Comment: Instead of extending the class *instance* (`turtle.Screen()`), you need to use the class itself, which is `turtle._Screen`. And where you call `__init__` on `turtle.Screen()`, you need to instead use `super`

Comment: Please edit your question to add the language tag - I presume `python`. This will make it easier for people to find your question.

Comment: `turlte.Screen` isn't a class - its a function designed to handle a singleton `turtle._Screen` class. If you create your own class you also need to make sure that your code doesn't also try to use the singleton.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are trying to inherit from a class instance rather than from a class. Note that when you are doing

```
class Screen(turtle.Screen()):
```

you are creating a new instance of the `turtle._Screen` class.
To fix this error, you just have to inherit from the right class as such:

```
class Screen(turtle._Screen):

    # Create and define an object
    def __init__(self, title, bgcolor, height, width, tracer = 0):
        
        # Note that here I use super() to access the parent class instead of creating a new instance with turtle.Screen()
        super().__init__(self)

        # Assign attribute to our instance
        self.title = title
        self.bgcolor = bgcolor
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.tracer = tracer
```

Hope this helps you